# Limit to above and below mongodb

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following query:

```
var score = 44;

      return Family.find({score: score}).then(function (war_response) {
            return war_response;
        })
```

but im looking for a way to only get the results that are 10 above my score, and 5 below, ( a total of 15 result/rows).^

How would the best way to accomplish this be?

EDIT:

so i want the 1-10 results above my score, and the 1-5 results below my score.

Comment: You can do two queries.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Why would you run two queries? That creates needless overhead. The collection could be massive.

Comment: Is it possible to do it in one query @Adam ?

Comment: @Adam: needless? I'd like to see how to do this in one. And collection size concern mostly goes away with proper indexing.

Answer (score 2):

```js
async yourRequest(){

  const myScore = 44;
  const resultsAboveMyScore = 10;
  const resultsBelowMyScore = 5;

  const aboveTheLimit = await Family.find({ 
      score: { $gte: myScore } 
    }).limit(resultsAboveMyScore);
  const belowTheLimit = await Family.find({ 
      score: { $lte: myScore } 
    }).limit(resultsBelowMyScore);

  return [...aboveTheLimit, ...belowTheLimit];
}
```